# Runtime datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I want to design datagridview at run time I want it to fill with data and appear on the form according to comboboxtext and if combobox is empty it disappear and when I click on datagridview I want the cell to be selectedvalue in the combobox and datagriddisapear
And here the code that I tried

```
Private Sub ComDr_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles ComDr.KeyPress
    Dim d As New DataGridView
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DAL().selectdatatable(String.Format("select Dr_Name,Dr_No from DR where Dr_Name like '%{0}%'", ComDr.Text))

    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then

        ' Try
        Controls.Add(d)
        d.DataSource = dt
        d.BringToFront()
        With d
            .Name = "Dr_Name"
            .Width = ComDr.Width
            .AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill
            .ColumnHeadersHeight = 30
            .Height = 10 * 35
            .ForeColor = Color.Blue
            .BackgroundColor = Color.Beige
            .RowHeadersVisible = False
            .BackgroundColor = Color.BurlyWood
            '.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.Yellow
            ' .DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.Black
            ' .DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("tahoma", 13)
            .Location = New System.Drawing.Point(680, ComDr.Location.Y + 30)
            .SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect

        End With

        For i As Integer = 0 To d.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim row As DataGridViewRow = d.Rows(i)
            row.Height = 35
            d.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = If(i Mod 2 = 0, Color.Wheat, Color.BurlyWood)
        Next

        AddHandler d.CellClick, AddressOf d_cellclick


        'ComDr.DisplayMember = d(0, d.SelectedRows(0).Index).Value.ToString
        'ComDr.ValueMember = d(1, d.SelectedRows(0).Index).Value.ToString
        'ComDr.Text = String.Empty
        'Controls.Remove(d)

        ' ComDr.SelectedValue = d(0, d.SelectedRows(0).Index).Value.ToString

        'Catch ex As Exception
        'MsgBox(ex.Message)
        'End Try
        ' Controls.Remove(d)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You appear to have forgotten to tell us what the problem is...

Comment: the problem  is the datagridview not disappear when the combox text is empty  and nothing happen when i click on acell